# Binding a label.Text to a String that gets updated from async task in Xamarin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, binding, task

So i'm having a Monitor Page in Xamarin where i need values to be refreshed every second (the values obtained from a TcpClient).
I set up a public String in my CS file and did some basic Binding in Xaml like this: `<Label Text="{Binding myString}"/>`

In my code behind i got an async Task running that refreshes the `myString`. The task looks something like this:

```
protected async Task syncDisplay(){
            while(true){
                //TcpClient going on, getting some values
                myString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            }
        }
```

And then i'm just creating a new Thread where i run the Task. That's all. The problem is that no value gets updated to my UI. When i try to assign a value to the String outside of the Task it works fine. I am sure i'm missing something essential here but i don't really know what.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update `myString` on the ui/main thread

Comment: is your myString setter calling PropertyChanged()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) are you using MVVM in your apprication

2) If yes than you need make sure you set DataContext  in your `View`

3) In your viewModel(VM) you need make property from `myString`

```
    private string _myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get => _myString;
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => MyString);
        }
    }
```

4) All code that couse UI update MUST be in UI Thread, like this

```
protected async Task syncDisplay(){
        while(true){
            //TcpClient going on, getting some values
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>MyString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the update to UI thread and adjusting my Setter by adding PropertyChanged did the job!